# Pass data on Back navigation in Ionic5 and Angular Router

Tags: routes, angular-routing, ionic5

I am using Angular Routers for navigation in my Ionic 5 app.

```
this.router.navigate(['/home/user/' + uid]);
```

When I am coming back to the HomePage using the back button, I want the user changes should reflect on the HomePage.

I tried passing the data with DataResolver but it worked well for forward navigation as the nav data is always bound with the ID of the current page. One way to achieve this will be using rxjs Subjects and subscribing to any changes in user data. Is there a way to use Angular Router feature to achieve this?